# What was normal attire for Hindu kings in the 15th century?

Tags: india, fashion

I was reading through "[A History of India](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/India.html?id=ibLUu6RlvqwC&redir_esc=y)" by John Keay when I came across a few paragraphs which talk about Hindu kings' attire (or the lack of it) in the 15th century. Travellers like Ibn Battuta, Marco Polo and Abdur Razzaq gave evidences in their accounts for the native non-Muslim kings wearing little to nothing at all, women going about the streets with bare breasts, etc.

These accounts seem to specifically refer to the hot Southern parts of India. What about North Indian rulers? Were the Mauryan and Guptan rulers unused to clothes too? And in South India, could we ascertain when (non-Muslim) rulers started clothing themselves? How about the Vijayanagara kings and the Maratha kings, Shivaji and Shambhaji?

Comment: How do you define proper clothes?

Comment: @Luke: Covering most of the body, perhaps. Something significantly more expansive than loincloth or two-piece, eg.

Comment: @Shyam You need to change the wording: "proper" is not the proper way of asking this question.

Comment: ...in the meantime, I'm putting irony quotes around the word in the title, so it will at least be clear that its a certian opinion of `proper` that is being asked about.

Comment: Remember to a medieval european, 'almost naked' might just mean not arrayed in the same finery a C13 King or Pope would be! Perhaps a simple robe?

Comment: everything you read cannot be true :) do you have any other references for this ?

I don't think this is actually true. Sari(or Saree) used to be the "proper" and traditional clothes for women from a long time.

Also most of the paintings (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sari) of women from the olden days picture women having a robe wrapped around them!

Comment: @Jayaram: All available documents of medieval travellers like Marco Polo, Ibn Battutta, Ferishta, etc agree with this point. I have reasons to suspect the Wiki article on saree and the references therein.

Comment: @Jayaram Those same paintings, you'll note, feature women wearing saris sans blouses! Blouses were *de mode* only after the Mughal kings took power.

Comment: @Aarthi>>british introduced blouse

Comment: If nudity is considered proper in a society, wearing any clothes at all is improper.

Comment: add to that, in many societies nudity is/was considered a sign of purity, innocence. It's really only in the traditions of the Abrahamic religions of Judaism, Christianity, and Islam (and the cultures that created or were strongly influenced by them) that strong nudity taboos exist.

Comment: @jwenting agreed

Comment: @Bravo I recently read the book too, can you specify the exact location where this particular thing is mentioned?

Answer (score 8):

South India has had a [vast number of kingdoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_kingdoms_of_India) , each having its own variety and having being influenced differently from other kingdoms , in culture , custorms , religion , art , language and of course the attire of all classes of society.

So it's not wise to put them in one general basket called *south india*.

Since it is not possible to quantitatively analyse all the kingdoms , let me consider a few notable dynasties that have reigned this region over a period of few centuries.

> Travellers like Ibn Battuta, Marco Polo and Abdur Razzaq give
>   evidences in their accounts for the native non-Muslim kings wearing
>   little to nothing at all.

Yes to some extent, you are right , the south indian kings of the chola dynasty in the 12 to 14 century AD, did not clothe their upper body, as evident in the portrait of the famous Chola king [**Rajendra Chola I**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajendra_Chola_I)

[image: Painting of Rajendra chola]

Here is a depiction of a King known as Cheraman Perumal from the [**Chera Dynasty**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chera_Dynasty) , who were in power till the 12 century.

[image]

So yes in short , certain Kings up to 13 - 14 Century AD , from various kingdoms, were bare chested , but in no way , "wearing little to nothing at all" , and in my opinion they were quite **"properly"** dressed .

> What about North Indian rulers? Were the Mauryan and Guptan rulers
>   unused to clothes too?

These kingdoms range roughly in the time period of 600 BCE to 100 BCE , little is recorded about the attire of kings during this period (or atleast whatever i could find was not sufficient).

The Gupta king [**Kumaragupta I**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaragupta_I) , depicted in the coin below , appears to be bare chested , and having a similar attire of his south Indian counterparts , centuries later.

[image: Kumaragupta I]

And below is the sculpture of the famous Mauryan King [Ashoka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka) , who according to me was one of the first indian king , to have a firm hold on all the Indian states , till the british conquered India , as a whole once again , after nearly 2000 years.

The Attire of Ashoka , is similar to the Gupta kings , having no cloth on the upper body but having an elaborate neck ornament.

For the first time India(the majority of it) has one single Emperor, this is a major opportunity , for the Indians to finally have a unified culture and tradition , this includes the attire. But the unified period is not long enough , to achieve this.

[image: Emperor Ashoka]

> How about the Vijayanagara kings and the Maratha kings, Shivaji and
>   Shambhaji?

Here is the portrait of King shivaji.

[image: King Shivaji]

By the time of 15 Century , all the kings of india , by now under the influence of the mughal emperors , and later under influence of [**portuguese**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_India) , and the [**dutch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_India) , who were the first europeans to arrive before the french and english , had started to change their appearance , they wore dresses , which showed foreign influence , but which did not completely lose the traditional touch.

Here is the statue of the famous [**king Krishnadevaraya**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishnadevaraya) , who ruled the prosperous [**Vijayanagara Empire**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayanagara_Empire) , which encompasses , almost the entire region of south india.

[image: King Krishnadevaraya]

From this point on (till date) , almost all kings of both North/South India , had a similar outfit.

Have a look at the [**present King**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srikanta_Wadiyar) (ceremonial only king) of Mysore.

[image: Mysore Maharaja]

As it is visually clear that the 21st century royal attire has undergone only a certain number of changes from its 15 Century counterpart , preserving the overall basic structure.

Comment: and do remember that climate differences can greatly influence mode of dress. A mountain area in the far north would not be a very pleasant place most of the year to go around (almost) naked, a tropical region in the south would likewise not be very comfortable when wearing thick woolen clothes the people in that mountain village would need to survive the winter...

Comment: Are the first two images contemporaneous?

Comment: @jwenting , a fine point made , however this answer is limited to the actual facts on the dress and not the influence behind the dress itself

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Yes they are contemporaneous but they have around 50 to 75 yrs difference , and also they belong to different dynasties of adjacent kingdoms.

Comment: @BarathBushan: Thanks for the answer. While I appreciate the depiction on Kumaragupta's coin (provided it is genuine), the other evidence that you are present are flimsy at best. Portraits of Chola kings are not real and were drawn by artists who had a free rein on their imagination.

Comment: @BarathBushan: In fact I really wonder if Chola kings were fair at all - I remember reading somewhere that they looked very dark. Moreover these pictures seem to contradict the travellers' accounts which say even women roamed around bare-breasted on the streets.

Comment: `"Portraits of Chola kings are not real and were drawn by artists who had a free rein on their imagination"`     Best of luck on your time travel to the 11 century with your dslr camera :)

Comment: @Shyam `In fact I really wonder if Chola kings were fair at all - I remember reading somewhere that they looked very dark.` First of all you really wonder a lot of things and then you expect the artist to maintain an exact measure of skin tone of a 11 century king , really ??

Comment: @BarathBushan: Be patient. Stackexchange answers are supposed to be based on reliable evidence. The question arose because I read it from a reputable book. If your answer talked about Hieun Tsang or Ibn Battuta's accounts, then I will have no reason to question its veracity.

Comment: You simply cannot put some pictures from history textbooks - especially when it is so many centuries old. The real story is got from archaeological evidence and from corroborative understanding from travellers' accounts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8016/discussion-between-shyam-and-barath-bushan)

Comment: @Shyam where do you think those pictures come from? And do you really think you're going to find archeological evidence of the skin colour of a man 1000 years dead, unless it be pictures created at some point by someone, which you'd then question as being "artistic license" if you don't like that they show?

Comment: @jwenting: Not archaeological evidence for skin color, but mentions in credible accounts of Marco Polo/Ibn Battuta, etc.

Comment: @Shyam Marco Polo is not a credible source. It is by now seriously doubted he even existed, and if he did most likely his "accounts" were romanticised fragments of stories he'd been passed on by others, often through word of mouth over the length of the silk route (people did not travel the entire silk route, rather they traveled a section back and forth, trading at either end).